# EditText end icon changes automatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, icons

**EditText icon not working correctly**

In EditText I added end icon `app:endIconDrawable="@mipmap/edit_icon"` for all icon it turns into gray square

**Updated code**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_user_name_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:hint="@string/user_name"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        app:endIconTintMode="screen"
        app:endIconDrawable="@mipmap/edit_icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_user_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Actual icon**

[image: Actual Icon]

**Output of Updated code**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `app:endIconTintMode="screen"` should fix the problem . Also for me icon is not visible without this attribute `app:endIconMode="custom"`

Comment: now icon is visible but still same gray square is there in background see updated question

Comment: This grey background is there due to background of png image resource , you can fix that by  using `app:endIconTint="@android:color/transparent`